# inline multi-line code doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: phpdoc

The documentation provides an example of a multi-line inline code tag:

http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.example.pkg.html

I'd expect the whole thing to be wrapped in a `<pre>` block or something but that is not what I get when I try it:

```
<?php
/**
 * test script - short description
 *
 * long description
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * code sample:
 * <code>
 * <?php
 * include('filename.php');
 *
 * dostuff();
 * domorestuff();
 * ?>
 * </code>
 */
class test {}
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

ie. one new line is treated as a space, two are treated as a new line and there are gaps between the highlighting.

Am I doing it wrong or is this really the best you can do with phpdoc?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're reading the manual for phpDocumentor 1.x but actually running 2.x, which is significantly different.  Doublecheck the 2.x docs at http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html.

Comment: So is there a way to do in-line code examples in phpdoc? In the 2.x docs I see http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/example.html but that seems to be just external examples - not in-line ones.

Comment: Changes are good that you'll need to use some Markdown syntax when laying out your code example.  That's probably why you're seeing such a difference between one-space and two-space behavior.